# Call ts file from html getting "Refused to execute script" error

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, compiler-errors, mime-types

I am calling a `typescript` file in a `html` file but am getting the following error:

`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/index.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.`

I want to add an eventListener to a `p` tag in my ts file but am not able to,

My script:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>My Class</title>
</head>
<body>
     <p class="myClass" id="myID">Click Here</p>

<script src="index.ts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `.ts`. file: `index.ts`

```
document.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML);
});
```

Once I reload my page, I am getting the error mentioned above and nothing happens when I click my `p` tag either.

Comment: Transpile to JavaScript first.